# Sliding Drawer Menu from right to left

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

[image]

I already achieved this Sliding Menu from left to right, i got a very easy and helpful tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

I was really amazed and puzzled on how 9Gag android app did this Sliding menu drawer from right to left for their notification `Fragment`, like this photo (below).

Any one who can help me out here? If you guys know any pointers and tutorials please help :) Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `SlidingMenu` or `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: Its a SlidingMenu @gunar :)

Answer (score 0):

Set layout_gravity to end on the fragment / view you want on the right.

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `android:layout_gravity="start"` for your **ListView** to display navigation drawer from Right to Left.

From Android Docs

> The drawer view (the ListView) must specify its horizontal gravity
>   with the android:layout_gravity attribute. To support right-to-left
>   (RTL) languages, specify the value with "start" instead of "left" (so
>   the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).